# issue with DLOOKUP syntax error for new database

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a database with 4 tables but primarily it is a diversion table/form (DiversionT/F) and a payback table/form (PaybackT/F). Basically, when my program loans parts to other programs in my organization a diversion is created in DiversionT. When the program want to payback they create a payback entry in PaybackT.

I have an issue that I am confused about: On PaybackF the user enters an NSN (long part code) that they want to payback. Ultimately, I want some of the form to auto populate with part info based on the NSN entered. The info is stored in DiversionT. I have created a few text boxes on PaybackF to show the info. The first text box I am trying to autofill based on the NSN is a textbox called PartName. It should search DiversionT for that NSN and fill in the appropriate PartName on PaybackF. In the control Source for the box I typed:

```
=DLookUp("[PartName]","[DiversionT]", "[PartName]=" & Forms![PaybackF]!NSN)
```

I get the following error:

> The expression you entered contains invalid syntax.

To be perfectly honest I don't really understand VBA yet (spent my life until now with C, C++, Java, and Python) but looked up the function on the Microsoft site.

If I am not going about this right, please also let me know?

Answer (score 0):

You can't enter VBA in to form properties like source control. VBA is only used in procedural code in the VBE. That being said, there is a DLOOKUP function available to form fields and the syntax is similar. This is a cause of your confusion.

EXAMPLE SYNTAX FOR NUMBERS:

```
=DLookUp("[PartName]","DiversionT", "[PartName]=" & [NSN])
```

EXAMPLE SYNTAX FOR STRINGS:

```
=DLookUp("[PartName]","DiversionT", "[PartName]='" & [NSN] & "'")
```

NOTE:
 I can't tell what form you are on  or if NSN is from a parent form or subform. Basically, NSN needs to be readable from the same form where that text field exists.

Comment: I am entering the NSN on the Payback Form and I want to take that entry and search the Diversion Table for the PartName associated with it and return it to the Payback Form as a check for the user. I plan to do something similar for other fields on this form such as using the customer name and the NSN to pull up how many they owe so they can enter an appropriate amount.

Comment: I copied your line of code and get #Error. Just to clarify the NSN field is in both the Payback table and the Diversion table. Should I rename one of them? I guess I dont understand the parent form or subform comment. This form was created from the Payback table but I want to display some info from the Diversion table on the form based on the info they entered for the NSN on the payback from.

Comment: NSN must be an object on the form where this DLOOKUP appears. Whatever table is behind the form is the one that will be correlated with. If NSN shows up in multiple tables then you need to research database normalization and relationships which is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Yes NSN is in both tables. I was using it as one way to link the tables.  I will do that research.

Comment: NSN also needs to be an object on the Form. The lookup is using an object named NSN on the form to compare with PartName. It might be as simple as adding NSN to the form and changing it's property .Visible = False.

Comment: okay it is on the form. I will check the visibility. It may not be good database technique but I want the user entered NSN on the form and payback  to link to the same nsn in the diversion table and display the associated partname to that NSN.

Comment: The visible false is only if you want to hide the field from the user but use it in a DLOOKUP.

Answer (score 0):

When using DLookup to get data, if you are dealing with text strings, you need to ensure that you use single quotes to wrap the text in.

Also, I think that your logic in the DLookup is slightly wrong. I think that this is what you are after:

```
=DLookUp("[PartName]","[DiversionT]", "[NSN]='" & Me!NSN & "'")
```

Regards,

Comment: What would the Me be? I put in the form the number is getting entered into in for Me and I get #Name? in the Part Name text field on the form.

Comment: `Me!NSN` refers to the control called NSN on the current form. If your textbox is called something else like Text0, then you would use `Me!Text0`.